# I/O error reported by XML parser processing file when running XSLT (Saxon PE 9.8.0.4J)

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

We are beginning the process of migrating from a lightly-modified version of the NLM Journalpublishing 3.0 DTD to a lightly-modified version of the JATS v1.2 DTD for our in-house editing and processing. I have been working on the initial setup and testing of our editing and document processing tools. We have 4 XSLT transformations that are used during various parts of the production process. We are using Saxon PE 9.8.0.4J to run our transformations on a Linux server.

The only change I made to the first XSLT I am testing was to update the doctype-system and doctype-public attributes on the `<xsl-output>` element.

When I run our command: **ng net.sf.saxon.Transform -xsl:/develop/lib/code/verify/verify.xsl -s:/jrnls/AN/v000n000/59613/59613.tmp -o:/jrnls/AN/v000n000/59613/59613.xml -catalog:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/catalog.ucpj-jats.xml -config:/opt/SaxonPE9-8-0-4J/UCPJconfig.xml ms-directory=/jrnls/AN/v000n000/59613**

I get this error: **I/O error reported by XML parser processing file:/jrnls/AN/v000n000/59613/59613.tmp: /jrnls/AN/v000n000/59613/JATS-journalpublishing-oasis-article1-mathml3.dtd (No such file or directory)**

We are using an almost identical command line for processing our current files in the Journalpublishing 3.0 DTD but using a different catalog file. We are having no problems with processing our current files.

I used our Journalpublishing 3.0 catalog file as an example when I setup the JATS 1.2 catalog file. I've tried using the JATS 1.2 catalog both without a `<group>` element and with a `<group>` element with the xml:base attribute specified. I got the same result either way.

I did setup a framework in Oxygen to test this XSLT and it works as expected.

Can anyone suggest any solutions to this problem? Any advice would greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error seems to come from the XML parser processing the XML input, I am not sure why any `xsl:output` change could affect that. So how does a minimal XML document sample look, how does its `DOCTYPE` declaration look? Does the file `/jrnls/AN/v000n000/59613/JATS-journalpublishing-oasis-article1-mathml3.dtd` or at least is the input in its DTD referencing a file named `JATS-journalpublishing-oasis-article1-mathml3.dtd` but your catalogue should tell the XML parser to find it in a different place than the one the error occurs for? Can you run with `-t` to get more detailed error messages?

Comment: To be clear, I don't think that the change to the `xsl:output` had any impact on the error I was getting but I thought I should include that information.

Comment: When I run the command with `-t`, here is the output I get:
`Saxon-PE 9.8.0.4J from Saxonica`
`Java version 1.8.0_272`
`Stylesheet compilation time: 87.553897ms`
`Processing file:/jrnls/AN/v000n000/59613/59613.tmp`
`Using parser org.apache.xml.resolver.tools.ResolvingXMLReader`
`Building tree for file:/jrnls/AN/v000n000/59613/59613.tmp using class net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyBuilder`
`I/O error reported by XML parser processing file:/jrnls/AN/v000n000/59613/59613.tmp: /jrnls/AN/v000n000/59613/JATS-journalpublishing-oasis-article1-mathml3.dtd (No such file or directory)`

Answer (score 0):

I googled “xerces resolver.jar" and one of the results was to the Apache XML Project Resolver Overview page (https://xerces.apache.org/xml-commons/components/resolver/). From there I went to “XML Entity and URI Resolvers” (https://xerces.apache.org/xml-commons/components/resolver/resolver-article.html).

In the first footnote on that page, the author includes a command line for parsing an XML file with a catalog:

```
$ java org.apache.xml.resolver.apps.xparse -d 2 -c catalog.xml example.xml
```

Which I modified to run on our server:

```
% ng org.apache.xml.resolver.apps.xparse -d 2 
  -c /develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/catalog.ucpj-jats.xml 
  /jrnls/AN/v000n000/59613/59613.xml
```

I got this output:

```
Attempting validating, namespace-aware parse
Loading catalog: /develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/catalog.ucpj-jats.xml
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) Journal Publishing DTD with OASIS Tables with MathML3 v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-journalpublishing-oasis-article1-mathml3.dtd
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) Journal Publishing DTD with OASIS Tables DTD-Specific Modules v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-journalpub-oasis-custom-modules1.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) JATS MathML 3.0 Modules v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-mathml3-modules1.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) JATS DTD Suite Module of Modules v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-modules1.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS ALI Namespace Module v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-ali-namespace1.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS OASIS Table Namespace Module v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-oasis-namespace1.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) JATS DTD Suite Common Attributes (for all elements) v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-common-atts1.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) Journal Publishing DTD with OASIS Tables Customize Classes v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-journalpub-oasis-custom-classes1.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) Default Element Classes Module v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-default-classes1.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) Journal Publishing DTD Customize Mixes Module v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-journalpubcustom-mixes1.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) Default Element Mixes Module v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-default-mixes1.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) Journal Publishing DTD Customize Content and Attributes Module v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-journalpubcustom-models1.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) JATS DTD Suite Common (Shared) Elements Module v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-common1.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) JATS DTD Suite Journal Article Metadata Elements v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-articlemeta1.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) JATS DTD Suite Back Matter Elements v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-backmatter1.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) JATS DTD Suite Display Class Elements v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-display1.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) JATS DTD Suite Formatting Element Classes v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-format1.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) JATS DTD Suite Funding Elements v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-funding1.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) JATS DTD Suite Journal Metadata Elements v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-journalmeta1.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) JATS DTD Suite Link Class Elements v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-link1.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) JATS DTD Suite List Class Elements v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-list1.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) JATS DTD Suite Math Class Elements v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-math1.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) NLM Citation v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-nlmcitation1.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) Namespaced OASIS XML Table Setup Module v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-oasis-tablesetup1.ent
Resolved public: -//OASIS//DTD XML Exchange Table Model 19990315//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/oasis-exchange.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) JATS DTD Suite Paragraph-Like Elements v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-para1.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) JATS DTD Suite Subject Phrase Class Elements v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-phrase1.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) JATS DTD Suite Bibliographic Reference (Citation) Class Elements v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-references1.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) JATS DTD Suite Related Object Element v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-related-object1.ent
Resolved public: -//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) JATS DTD Suite Section Class Elements v1.2 20190208//EN
        file:/develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/JATS-section1.ent
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /develop/lib/code/saxon_JATS-1.2/BITS-embedded-index2.ent (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:623)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1304)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1240)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.startPE(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:740)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.skipSeparator(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:2109)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanDecls(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:2072)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanDTDExternalSubset(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:307)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1174)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1045)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:959)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1140)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:655)
        at org.apache.xml.resolver.tools.ResolvingParser.parse(ResolvingParser.java:183)
        at org.apache.xml.resolver.apps.xparse.main(xparse.java:186)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:278)
Parse succeeded (0.31) with no errors and no warnings.
```

Once I restored that missing file and added it to our catalog file, our command line worked as expected.